# Is there a way to make a hitTest in AS3 faster?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I have made a game in AS3 for android, and when I test it on my PC it works great, but when I try on Android, hitTests slow my game down a bit, for example I have one level where you have to collect 9 coins, and whenever your characters is about to collect it, game freezes for a bit, and the code I use is

```
if (coin1.hitTestObject(hero)){
coin1.visible=false;
gate.y-=10;
}
```

That is all, so basically only 2 tasks for the program to execute on hitTest, but it slows down the game... Also my game is only 600kb big, I don't think it's the other parts of the code, it doesn't have sounds or anything else, everything is only hitTests in the game basically...

Answer (score 1):

You could swap `hitTestObject` with another approach. Calculate distance to coins from hero, and remove them, if they are close enough. Such math should work faster:

```
var someDistance: Number = 4;
var dx: Number = hero.x - coin.x;
var dy: Number = hero.y - coin.y;

if(Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) <= someDistance){
    //Gotcha! Hero "collided" with coin
}
```

Comment: hmm, I will have to try, my code is 500 lines long, so it will take some time to replace it haha, thanks anyway